# Mac OS X installation fails

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, installation, operating-systems

W I started my Mac Mini only white screen with activity wheel shows up. No blue screen. I think my Mac is crashed.

Now when I inserted my Leopard DVD and rebooted, it didn't show me any option to install.

- What to do?
- Is there anything which can same my data?
- Do I need to format my Mac?
- Why isn't it not showing the menu to reinstall it?

Comment: WHy is it off topic ?

Comment: @Akshay Thakur Because questions on StackOverflow are for programming. You're much more likely to get an answer on SuperUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try booting while holding down the Option key, which will display all your boot options: cd, usb, hard drive, etc.  If that doesn't work, try targeted disk mode (You must have a firewire port and cable connected to another computer for this to be of any use): boot while holding the T key.  This will treat your mac like an external hard drive essentially, so you can retrieve any necessary data and re-install the operating system using another mac.

Answer (score 0):

You need to press and hold down the c key during boot. Only then will it start from DVD.

Comment: I did that but Didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a [support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2570) providing troubleshooting advice for refusal to boot issues.